# How to set Gutenberg preferences programmatically with wp.data.dispatch?

Tags: block-editor, options

The Gutenberg **Options > Preferences** menu contains a number of additional settings to customise the Gutenberg experience. The default GUI is shown below. I would like to programmatically enable the **Reduce the interface** option.

[image]

### Current code

Checking whether the option is enabled or not is simple with the `wp.data.select` function.

```
const reduceInterface = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' )
    .isFeatureActive( 'reduceInterface' )

console.log( reduceInterface )
```

This correctly shows `true`/`false` when the option for **Reduce the interface** is enabled/disabled through the GUI.

However changing the value programmatically with `wp.data.dispatch`, as would normally be done, doesn't seem to work.

```
if ( !reduceInterface ) {
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' )
        .toggleFeature( 'reduceInterface' )
}
```

No errors are thrown but the option is not changed.

### Question

How can Gutenberg preferences, specifically for **Reduce the interface**, be programmatically updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This correctly shows `true`/`false` when the option for **Reduce the interface** is enabled/disabled through the GUI.

Are you sure `isFeatureActive( 'reduceInterface' )` worked?

Because I looked at the source code (see `wp-includes/js/dist/edit-post.js`) and then I found out that the feature name is actually **`reducedUI`** and *not* `reduceInterface`.

So try with `reducedUI` instead:

```js
let reduceInterface = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isFeatureActive( 'reducedUI' );
console.log( 'before', reduceInterface );

wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleFeature( 'reducedUI' ); // enable/disable it

reduceInterface = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isFeatureActive( 'reducedUI' );

console.log( 'after', reduceInterface );
```

The above worked for me on WordPress 5.8 and 5.8.2 (the latest release as of writing).

Comment: Thanks, `reducedUI` is the way to go! I was dispatching a toggleFeature to `reduceInterface` which made it coincidentally log the same values as I was manually setting the preference to.